# Just like html pages are coded in a text editor and saved as .html, can we do the same thing by coding a jpg file?

Tags: image

Just like html pages are coded in a text editor and saved as .html, can we do the same thing by coding a .jpg file?
How are jpg files coded and built?

Comment: JPEG is not an image description language, it's a compression method. If I understand correctly, you want to 'describe' an image (say, by specifying circles and rectangles with position, size, and color) and save *that* as a JPEG. (But, typically JPEG is used for photos and photo-like images.)

Comment: could you tell me which language is used for image description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jongware already said in his comment, JPEG is a compression method. Just open a JPEG file in a text editor, and you will see that it doesn't look like something that can be created by hand at all.

If you want to "code" an image, you can't use a bitmap image format like JPEG - you need a vector image format ([see this for an explanation about the difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_image_format)).

There are probably more, but the first one that comes to my mind is SVG ([Wikipedia article about SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)).

You "code" SVG files in XML, and all modern browsers are able to render it.

Here is an example, copied from [the German version of the Wikipedia article above](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics):
*(the English article didn't have a linkable rendered example file, just the source code. So I took the example from the German article and just translated the comment)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
        width="700px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 700 400">

        <!-- connectors left and right -->
        <line x1="0" y1="200" x2="700" y2="200" stroke="black" stroke-width="20px"/>
        <!-- the rectangle -->
        <rect x="100" y="100" width="500" height="200" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="20px"/>
        <!-- the arrow line -->
        <line x1="180" y1="370" x2="500" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="15px"/>
        <!-- the tip of the arrow -->
        <polygon points="585 0 525 25 585 50" transform="rotate(135 525 25)"/>
</svg>
```

The rendered image looks like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Variable_Resistor.svg

Comment: Yes, SVG is probably the best way to "write" an image by hand these days. While you can't create JPEGs by hand (well, not unless you're a *really* scary person), you may also want to look into libraries/programs like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), or [GD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library) that will allow you to "build" raster images through scripting with commands that let you "draw line", "draw circle", etc. and export the results in JPEG format.

Comment: Nice. It answered my question. To convert the svg image to bitmap/jpeg is there an algorithm? or another programming language?

Comment: Concerning conversion, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019462/how-to-convert-svg-files-to-other-image-formats) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/convert-png-to-svg) *(for example)*. If my answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: Christian Specht I liked the answer. It answered my question really well. But i need minimum 15 reputation to answer it