# Unocov and libreoffice command line .svg conversion error

Tags: svg, libreoffice, file-conversion, ubuntu-13.10, uno

I'm trying to convert .png to .svg files using unoconv. The command line tool seems to work well with other formats, but is giving me the following error for conversion to svg files specifically:

```
    $ unoconv -f svg ./sample.png

    Unable to store document to file:///sample.svg (ErrCode 3088)
```

I've successfully used the tool with other formats, and the [unoconv page](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/) even indicates that the .svg ouput format is supported.

I thought the issue might have something to do with the libreoffice used by unoconv, so I tried using the libreoffice command line tool directly. I used both of the following commands with no success:

```
    ./soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to svg --outdir ./result ./sample.png  


    ./soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to svg:"impress_svg_Export" --outdir ./result ./sample.png
```

Both commands resulted in `Error: Please reverify input parameters...`, although the first command worked perfectly for when `jpeg` was used rather than `svg`.

Comment: How do you want to convert it? It's trivial to add an svg wrapper around the png, but it seems you want to trace the bitmap, correct? That's not a simple conversion, see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/convert-png-to-svg.