# How to create icons like font awesome

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, font-awesome

I am new to web development. And in my sample project to get icons I have included the font-awesome plugin (http://fontawesome.io/icons/). And I can select all sort of icons available. But I have two three `project specific images` like the `project logo`.

Question 1: How can I convert project specific images (png) to icons like "font-awesome"

Question 2: I searched a little and then found that the are nothing but files with svg extension. So, if I convert the images that I already have in SVG format will that be sufficient.

Question 3: So, once I create SVG icons will I be able to apply the CSS styling as I apply on "font-awesome" icons.

I am new to all this. Please guide me.

Comment: I highly doubt that I asked for any book or any plug in recommendation. I did my homework before asking and then posted my question. I have got a satisfactory answer which DOES NOT have any book recommendation per se. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Question 1: How can I convert project specific images (png) to icons like "font-awesome"**

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/convert-png-to-svg)

> A png is a bitmap image style and an SVG is a vector-based graphics
>   design which supports bitmaps so it's not as if it would convert the
>   image to vectors, just an image embedded in a vector-based format. You
>   could do this using http://www.inkscape.org/ which is free. It would
>   embed it, however it also has a Live Trace like engine which will try
>   to convert it to paths if you wish (using potrace).

**Question 2: I searched a little and then found that the are nothing but files with svg extension. So, if I convert the images that I already have in SVG format will that be sufficient.**

Yes

**Question 3: So, once I create SVG icons will I be able to apply the CSS styling as I apply on "font-awesome" icons.**

You could add it to the font-awesome library manually. On the other hand, instead of pulling out your hair doing it, you should use an online tool that helps you create a custom library for your icons. I've used [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select), and [flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/) with success in the past.