# rectangular box with one side diagonal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-relativelayout

I want to create a custom View similar to this image. More specifically, the dark "**number of riders**" view. I don't want to use an image for background. I need a drawable xml for the background.

I am new to Android so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is the required image]

Comment: Please share the image. Thanks

Comment: Image added @TarunGupta

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that will be to use a 9-patch drawable file and set it as the background of the TextView.
Here is how you can do that: http://en.miui.com/thread-26099-1-1.html

Or you can create an SVG and use that as background. The easiest way to do that would be to make a png image and convert it to SVG file using online converters.
[How to convert a PNG image to a SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/convert-png-to-svg)

There is more complicated way to archive it like drawing on a canvas and using that as background, But I would recommend you to use 9-patch file.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Lokesh but i have already mentioned that i don't want to use an image , I need a drawable xml for the background.

Comment: That's what I wrote in 2nd option. You can generate an SVG from a PNG image and import it into your project.  It will be vector drawable  https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#svg