# Png-based icon: Low-res: blurry on iPhone, clear on IE, High-res: Blurry on IE, clear on iPhone

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a png based icon that I want to embed inside an input box, with CSS:

`background:url(/images/icon.png) 20px 20px no-repeat #fff;`

It should be 20*20 PX

If I use a high res icon, say 100*100:
It's clear on iPhone, but sketchy on IE

If I use a 20*20 (lower res):

It's blurry on iPhone, and fine on IE.

[image]

What's the best trick to resolve this?

Comment: I think we may want to take a look at the evidence first.

Comment: Use SVG or a font-based icon instead?

Comment: @MrLister I added a photo

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan How Do I generate an SVG? The online tools I tried created a blank file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1861382/215552

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The only website that seems to work charges money for that, that's crazy. I would imagine that's a popular problem.

Comment: It's a pretty simple icon, I wouldn't be surprised if an SVG/font version is already out there. Try Font Awesome or [the Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=map%20pin).

Comment: NounProject gives only black color (unless I pay), I need gray color. and fontawesome, I don't want to download the whole library just for a single icon. So I'm still out of good solutions.