# How can I draw a single svg path with variable width stroking?

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I draw this shape using a single svg path?

[image]

Comment: those parts doesn't seem connected to each other, so probably no.

Comment: Let's assume that they are connected. Is it still not possible?

Comment: if they are connected, i would assume that you could draw it with only one svg path.

Comment: Yes or no, this question is a poor fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this yes / no question isn't a programming problem. If the question turns to "How do I do this", it's too broad.

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/147

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a PNG image to a SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/how-to-convert-a-png-image-to-a-svg)

Comment: Now that you changed the question to _"How"_, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a single path, but currently there's no such thing as variable width `stroke`. Instead, such a shape can be drawn using `fill` on a path criss-crossing itself:

```css
#hide-stroke:checked ~ svg path {
  stroke: none;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="hide-stroke" type="checkbox" />
<label for="hide-stroke">Hide stroke</label>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="300" viewBox="0,0 200,100" >
   <path d="M20,80  q26,-100 53,-25  q26,75 53,0  q26,-90 53,0  q-26,-70 -45,-10  q-26,80 -70,0  q-25,-40 -37,0" 
         fill="black" stroke-width="1" stroke="limegreen" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I can't add an answer  this question is closed. The answer is no you cannot do this in SVG as a single stroke. There is a proposal  to change SVG to support it: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Variable_width_stroke